# Adding dynamically elements on the win form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms. Clicking button on form1 opens form2 where user adds details and this is returned back to form1, information is stored to `List` and TextBoxes and other elements of interface are created.

I have 5 tabs for different levels but information added is the same.

How can I avoid creating similar code 5 times using

```
if (level==5) {//do this whole code again}
```

Example of element added:

```
int _nextTextBoxTop=15;
List<TextBox> CodesMy = new List<TextBox>();

var code = new TextBox();
CodesMy.Add(code);
code.Location = new Point(12, _nextTextBoxTop);
_nextTextBoxTop += 36;
code.Size = new Size(80, 25);
code.Text = mcode;
tabPageLevel5.Controls.Add.Controls.Add(code);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution could be to refactor your element creation into a separate function like this:

```
CreateControls(TabPage tabPage)
{
var code = new TextBox();
CodesMy.Add(code);
code.Location = new Point(12, _nextTextBoxTop);
_nextTextBoxTop += 36;
code.Size = new Size(80, 25);
code.Text = mcode;
tabPage.Controls.Add.Controls.Add(code);     
}
```

Your client code would then look like:

```
if (level==5) {CreateControls(tabPageLevel5);}
```

A simpler way than dynamically adding controls could be to create a user control that is used on each of your tab pages.

Even if you need to add controls dynamically you could still do it with a user control and clone it each time per each additional tab page.

Comment: Thats fine, I am just trying to avoid cloning this or its not possible

Comment: Ok that's fine. I do have one additional problem, although controls are the same Lists to which elements are added are different, becuase I need access to specific elements to do calculations. So I have:

List<TextBox> CodesMy = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> CodesMy2 = new List<TextBox>();......

Comment: There's a variety of ways to solve that. 2D array of TextBoxes or a list of lists like this: List<List<TextBox>>

Comment: can I have 3D, 4D array or just 2D

Comment: Yes, you can add as many dimensions as you wish: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be specifying the positions absolutely.  Create a `FlowLayoutPanel` and just add each new textbox (or usercontrol with all of the controls that represent the new "thing" to add) to that panel so that they get added just below the previous one.

The `FlowLayoutPanel` that you add them to can vary depending on which Tab you want to add them to.  You can make it a parameter to a method, similar to Paul's suggestion, or you can have a variable `currentTab`, `panelInCurrentTab` or something like that which is set appropriately, and then a method that simply adds the new controls to that container.

Comment: they are not absolute they are part of GroupBoxbut I haven't copied the same code. Edited the code